# passing request to a scala function

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a scala function that looks like:

```
 def myfunction(uname: Option[String]) = Action.async { request => ...
     ....
     if  isLoggedAPerson(request) {
         do_something
     }
     else
     {
        do_something_else
     }
     .
 }
```

I want to create a Scala function that will process the request:

```
 def isLoggedAPerson(request) : Boolean = {
        val reqType = request.session.get("sessionType").getOrElse("No session")
        if (reqType == "Admin" || reqType =="staff") return true
        else return false
 }
```

but I do not know the data type for request. Does anyone knows? am I missing something else?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `request` is [`play.api.mvc.Request[AnyContent]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request), as can be seen in the signature for [`Action.async`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$@async(block:R[B]=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]):play.api.mvc.Action[B]):

```
final def async(block: (Request[AnyContent]) => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent]
```

Therefore, `isLoggedAPerson` would look like:

```
def isLoggedAPerson(request: Request[AnyContent]): Boolean = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: you can also use the type `RequestHeader` if you only need to access the session